# Current map provided with laser scan

Tags: ros, navigation, learning-tf, gmapping, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am new in ROS and I want to do a SLAM using gmapping package with "laser scan" and "odometry data".
In the first step I just want to see the current map provided with laser scan in fixed location (x = 0, y = 0, theta = 0) in rviz.
I have laser scan topic but I don't have a odometry data yet, so I want to make a fake odometry data. For this I think I should publish a TF data with all zeros.
I think I should do some thing like this  [link](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#tf_echo):

1

2

3

Am I in the right path? could you please tell me what should I do in details? or show me some references?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192410/current-map-provided-with-laser-scan/) by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using a laser scanner, using hector_mapping can be easier than gmapping. Launch the mapping program and publish a 0,0,0 static transform between base_link and laser to account for your non existent odometry and you should be set.

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_tf" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100"/>
```

Just my two cents.

---

Originally posted by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) with karma: 275 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1